# Login to ssl website with php and cURL

Tags: php, post, curl, ssl

I'm trying to login to Square (squareup.com/login) to retrieve some information about my business and send me an email.  However, my ability to make cURL work properly has not made any progress for several days so I'm asking for help.

Here's my code:

```
$email = 'myemail';
$password = 'mypassword';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$tokenurl = 'https://squareup.com/login/'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenurl);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$get_auth_token = strstr($content, 'input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="');
$auth_token = substr($get_auth_token,53,44);

$loginUrl = 'https://www.squareup.com/login/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.$email.'&password='.$password.'&authenticity_token='.$auth_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$store = curl_exec($ch);

$fileurl = 'https://squareup.com/dashboard'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileurl);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents('data.txt', $content);
```

The result in my data.txt file is either the login page being displayed again (as in, it didn't login correctly).

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: change `$username` to `$email`

Comment: Update: Thanks user2092317 for the catch.  Updated code (still not working) with the automated auth token collection, although it's changing on every request now which may be the issue.